# Scrapy - how to crawl a website with a tree structure and keep the structure in the outputed Json file

Tags: python, json, tree, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website which has a tree structure, and i would like to recreate that tree structure in the outputed json file.

All the pages have the same structure, and I have to get some fields from a page, than go to each of the linked sub-pages and get the same fields, etc...

An item output in the json file would look like this, (this is simplified):

```
{"Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm", 
                  "Rattachement": ["ratt_a", "ratt_b"],
                  "Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm", 
                                   "Rattachement": ["ratt_a", "ratt_b"],
                                   "Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm",
                                                    "Rattachement": ["ratt_a", "ratt_b"],
                                                    "Organiation": [null]
                                     }],
                                   "Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm",
                                                    "Rattachement": ["ratt_a", "ratt_b"],
                                                    "Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm",
                                                                     "Rattachement":["ratt_a", "ratt_b"],
                                                                     "Organiation": [null]
                                                 }]
                                     }]
                        }]
            }]
}
```

What I have been able to do so for is to get an item per page:

```
{"Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm", "Rattachement": ["ratt_a", "ratt_b"], "Organisation" = ["orga1", "orga2", ...]]}
{"Organiation": [{"Administration": "name_adm", "Rattachement": ["ratt_a", "ratt_b"], "Organisation" = ["orga1", "orga2", ...]]}
etc...
```

I have spent much time trying to figure out a way to do it but with no success, I explored the option of recursivity but I haven't been able to make it work mainly because I don't now how to parse recursively using "callback" (see the code below for the parse function).

here is what i got so far:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for url in response.xpath('//ul[@class = "list-arrow list-narrow"]/li/a/@href').extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
    page = PageItem()  

    page['Administration'] = response.xpath('//div[@class = "panel-body"]/p/span/text()' ).extract()

    Rattachements = []        
    for site in response.xpath('//ul[@class ="list-connected"]/li'):
        Rattachements.append(site.xpath('a/text()').extract())
    page['Rattachement'] = Rattachements

    Organisations = [] 
    for site in response.xpath('//ul[@data-test="organizations"]/li/a'):
        Organisations.append(site.xpath('text()').extract())
    page['Organisation'] = Organisations
    yield page

    URLS = response.xpath('//ul[@data-test="organizations"]/li/a/@href').extract()
    for url in URLS:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```

This last piece of code allowed me to put each page in an item:

```
    URLS = response.xpath('//ul[@data-test="organizations"]/li/a/@href').extract()
    for url in URLS:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```

URLS are the links to the next-level sub-pages for a given page.

When I couldn't get the tree structure, the next best think was to put in "Organisation" the list of texts of the sub-pages links, but if i can get the tree structure, i won't need to keep this list in "Organisation".

How could I change the code so that I keep the tree structure of the website in the Json output.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the source code of your page in a pastebin and link it here?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gpmLgXHC

Answer (score 0):

Try using jsonmerge [jsonmerge](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonmerge) package to merge your current output together.

And return items when all merges are finished, you can use the idle handler to achieve that.